# Kill emacs subprocesses windows 10

Tags: powershell, emacs, process, windows-10

Is there a way to kill all the subprocesses spawned by emacs on windows 10?  I'm currently running an inferior nodejs repl from native win32 emacs build on windows 10.  Usually when an inferior shell hangs I can kill cmdproxy.exe processes or whatever the spawned process was and emacs will become "unhung".  However, I can't find the process associated with the inferior nodejs repl.

In nodejs-repl it names the process "nodejs", but that process isn't listed when I check with powershell.  Is there another method to find all the process spawned by emacs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do on Windows is use Sysinternals Process Explorer (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.) In its default Show Process Tree view you can see all processes spawned by emacs underneath it, and kill any or all of them, leaving emacs itself alive.

Procexp and Sysinternals in general are extremely convenient, if you don't use them give them a try.

If you are looking for a command line way of doing that, I think a bit or Powershell hacking may do it, but I've never found it necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This should work on any platform:

```lisp
(mapc #'kill-process (process-list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how I do this:

```
$procid = Get-WmiObject win32_process | where {$_.Path -like '*OpenWindowsServiceExchangeSyncAgent*'} | select processid
stop-process -id $procid.processid
```

The path should be different for each child/sub process of a process.